# Malformed JSON response being sent by Play Server

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, playframework

I am using jquery Ajax to send data to the client and get reply from the Client.
I am using Play Framework as backend.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/authenticate',
    data: {'type':type, 'redirectURL':getRedirectURL},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: 'json'
}).success(function( msg, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("asdasd5= "+msg);
    console.log("asdasd5= "+msg.authUrl);
    console.log("asdasd5= "+jqXHR.authUrl);
    window.location = msg;
});
```

SERVER DATA CREATION:

```
response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
Logger.info("response content type ="+response.contentType);
renderJSON("{\"authUrl\": " + authUrl +"}");
```

The server is sending something like "www.mywebsite.com/yoohoo/auth/1231"

But the response received by Ajax is `�����������������{"authUrl": www.mywebsite.com/yoohoo/auth/1231}`

DUE to these weird character the JSON response received cannot be parsed by jQuery.
Kindly, help on this.

Thanks

Comment: figure out where those extra chars are coming from. it won't be from the JS code - it'll be something server-side. Use a hexeditor to figure out WHAT those chars are (e.g. ascii code) and then dig through your code for that particular char.

Comment: Once the characters are removed, your JSON will still be invalid due to missing quotes around the url.

Comment: Do not use `.success`, instead, use the success option within the ajax options object. `.success` is deprecated and removed in recent versions. Alternatively you can use `.done`

Answer (score 0):

I noted that you are sending back (server-side) a MIME type of "text/plain". Perhaps switch to "application/json". Additionally, you could take the return string and strip any junk from the string before parsing the JSON out on the client side. This would help sanitize in case you change something again server-side and accidentally introduce new/different "junk".

Comment: I switched the data creation to "application/json"

But still the same problem.

The weird characters are not fixed, they wary in number so I cannot use SubString �����������������{"authUrl": www.mywebsite.com/yoohoo/auth/1231}

Can you suggest how to clean the string?

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing that the source of the data is encoded using one codepage (such as ISO-8859-1) but is being read in/converted to another (such as UTF-8).

Comment: `var s = ""; for(var i=0;i < message.length;i++) { if(message.charAt(i) != "\uFFFD") s+= message.charAt(i) };`  where message is the url returned from the call and s is a temp holder

Comment: Shorthand with regexp: `var s = message.replace(/[\uFFFD]/g,"");`

Comment: One last comment: check out the bottom of this page for the play framework: [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaResponse]